# how to add multiple counter in one redux in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to add multiple counter, like countA, countV, countR and want to update specific counter on onPress. but when I update any one of this. then all counter updating.

here is what i have try in App.js

```
const initialState={
  countA:0,
  countV:0,
  countR:0,

};



function reducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case "INCREMENTA":
      return {
        countA: state.countA + 1,
      }
      case "INCREMENTV":
      return {
        countV: state.countV + 1,
      }
      case "INCREMENTR":
      return {
        countR: state.countR+ 1,
      }
      default:
        return state;

  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);
```

in screen.js

```
incrementA = () => {
     this.props.dispatch({type:"INCREMENTA"})
    }

    incrementV = () => {
      this.props.dispatch({type:"INCREMENTV"})
     }

     incrementR = () => {
      this.props.dispatch({type:"INCREMENTR"})
     }

///here is onPress button



const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
  countA:state.countA,
  countV:state.countV,
  countR:state.countR
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(detailScreen);
```

please ignore it = I want to add multiple counter, like countA, countV, countR and want to update specific counter on onPress. but when I update any one of this. then all counter updating. I want to add multiple counter, like countA, countV, countR and want to update specific counter on onPress. but when I update any one of this. then all counter updating.

Answer (score 1):

In Redux reducers you have to return the whole new state, so your code should be:

```js
const initialState={
  countA:0,
  countV:0,
  countR:0,

};

function reducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case "INCREMENTA":
      return {
        ...state,
        countA: state.countA + 1,
      }
      case "INCREMENTV":
      return {
        ...state,
        countV: state.countV + 1,
      }
      case "INCREMENTR":
      return {
        ...state,
        countR: state.countR+ 1,
      }
      default:
        return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);
```